# Sitecore "HtmlCacheClearer clearing HTML caches for all sites"

Tags: asp.net, sitecore, sitecore6

In the Sitecore(v6.6 130404) log it is loaded with "HtmlCacheClearer clearing HTML caches for all sites" log entries.

Log extract: (Every second it records these logs)

```
ManagedPoolThread #3 18:59:22 INFO  HtmlCacheClearer clearing HTML caches for all sites (1).
ManagedPoolThread #3 18:59:22 INFO  HtmlCacheClearer done.
ManagedPoolThread #3 18:59:22 INFO  HtmlCacheClearer clearing HTML caches for all sites (1).
ManagedPoolThread #3 18:59:22 INFO  HtmlCacheClearer done.
ManagedPoolThread #3 18:59:23 INFO  HtmlCacheClearer clearing HTML caches for all sites (1).
ManagedPoolThread #3 18:59:23 INFO  HtmlCacheClearer done.
ManagedPoolThread #3 18:59:23 INFO  HtmlCacheClearer clearing HTML caches for all sites (1).
ManagedPoolThread #3 18:59:23 INFO  HtmlCacheClearer done.
ManagedPoolThread #3 18:59:23 INFO  HtmlCacheClearer clearing HTML caches for all sites (1).
ManagedPoolThread #3 18:59:23 INFO  HtmlCacheClearer done.
ManagedPoolThread #3 18:59:24 INFO  HtmlCacheClearer clearing HTML caches for all sites (1).
ManagedPoolThread #3 18:59:24 INFO  HtmlCacheClearer done.
```

How can I get rid of this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Sitecore.Publishing.HtmlCacheClearer.ClearCode()` method (which logs this information) is executed every time the `Publish` execution is done (on local server or remotely).

It looks like your application executes `Publish` quite often. If you think this might be a bug, try to investigate which items are being published (e.g. by adding a hander to `publish:itemProcessing` event) and check what calls `Publish` for them.

Comment: Thanks heaps, this is really helpful. One of our background agent was trying to publish items in a for loop. We have detected this and optimized the performance.